# GetAndDecrement Much Slower than GetAndIncrement.

Tags: java, atomic, atomicinteger

I have found that in Java using `AtomicIntegers`, `GetAndDecrement` is much slower than `GetAndIncrement`. Why does this happen?

Comment: This question is really vague. Can you back this up with evidence?

Comment: Wait actually... This is actually happening...

Comment: Can you post some statistics? I found that this did happen, can you test it and provide more direct evidence as well?

Answer (score 1):

Whichever one comes second is faster.

```
AtomicInteger a = new AtomicInteger(1);

long start1 = System.nanoTime();
a.decrementAndGet(); 
System.out.println("Time: " + (System.nanoTime()-start1));

AtomicInteger b = new AtomicInteger(1);

long start2 = System.nanoTime();
a.incrementAndGet();
System.out.println("Time: " + (System.nanoTime()-start2));
```

On my machine, this prints:

> Time: 49264
>
> Time: 4105

However, if we swap the order of the two operations:

```
AtomicInteger a = new AtomicInteger(1);

long start1 = System.nanoTime();
a.incrementAndGet();
System.out.println("Time: " + (System.nanoTime()-start1));

AtomicInteger b = new AtomicInteger(1);

long start2 = System.nanoTime();
a.decrementAndGet();
System.out.println("Time: " + (System.nanoTime()-start2));
```

Then we get:

> Time: 43106
>
> Time: 7697

Presumably the JVM or processor or something is doing some runtime optimizations.

Answer (score -1):

They look pretty much the same to me --

```
public final int getAndIncrement() {
    for (;;) {
        int current = get();
        int next = current + 1;
        if (compareAndSet(current, next))
            return current;
    }
}

public final int getAndDecrement() {
    for (;;) {
        int current = get();
        int next = current - 1;
        if (compareAndSet(current, next))
            return current;
    }
}
```

Comment: Run it. When I ran it, the getAndDecrement() method took 5 times longer. Run and time it, don't post hypotheticals.

Comment: That's just the source code (admittedly a bit old).  Would've been a comment but it wouldn't be legible that way.

Comment: (It may be that newer implementations have moved the more popular increment to a native method, or some such.)

Comment: This is the same as the newest implementation.

Comment: There's still a chance that increment is being overridden by a native implementation.  The other, perhaps more likely possibility is that the JITC optimizes the increment but not the decrement, possibly because of the presence of native instructions to do the former.